# Working with large text files?

Tags: f#

I need to import a large text file (55MB) (525000 * 25) and manipulate the data and produce some output. As usual I started exploring with f# interactive, and I get some really strange behaviours.

Is this file too large or my code wrong?

First test was to import and simply comute the sum over one column (not the end goal but first test):

```
let calctest =
let reader = new StreamReader(path)
let csv = reader.ReadToEnd()    
csv.Split([|'\n'|])
|> Seq.skip 1
|> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Split([|','|]))
|> Seq.filter (fun a -> a.[11] = "M")
|> Seq.map (fun values -> float(values.[14]))
```

As expected this produces a seq of float both in typecheck and in interactive. If I know add:

```
|> Seq.sum
```

Type check works and says this function should return a float but if I run it in interactive I get this error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array
```

Then I removed the last line again and thought I look at the seq of float in a text file:

```
let writetest = 
let str = calctest |> Seq.map (fun i -> i.ToString())
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("test.txt", str )
```

Again, this passes the type check but throws errors in interactive.

Can the standard StreamReader not handle that amount of data? or am I going wrong somewhere? Should I use a different function then Streamreader?
Thanks.

Comment: You are performing two different indexing operations on an array (once in the `filter` and once in the `map`). Perhaps a row in the input file has insufficient fields? Ie. the `string.spit` produces fewer than 12 or 14 values into the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Seq` is lazy, which means that only when you add the `Seq.sum` is all the mapping and filtering actually being done, that's why you don't see the error before adding that line. Are you sure you have 15 columns on all rows? That's probably the problem

I would advise you to use the [CSV Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) instead of just doing a `string.Split`, that way you'll be sure to not have an accidental IndexOutOfRangeException, and you'll handle `,` escaping correctly.

Additionaly, you're reading the whole csv file into memory by calling `reader.ReadToEnd()`, the CsvProvider supports streaming if you set the `Cache` parameter to false. It's not a problem with a 55MB file, but if you have something much larger it might be

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can actually run the function without Seq.sum and it returns a seq of float that is equivalent to column 15 without errors... I dont get it, but you are probably right, I will try to use the provider

Comment: When you call Seq.map and Seq.filter, nothing is enumerated, but when you evaluate it directly in FSI, it fetches the first few values for display, which means if the problem is on row 20, you won't notice it

Comment: @nik try accessing the last element, or printing them all so you are sure the Seq is fully realized.